# How do I put logical operations in a while loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, prompt

I want to create a guessing game where you pick a maximum number in the prompt and you type the number that the program randomly generates.

However, I want it so that when you press "q", the game quits automatically.

Here's my code

```
let maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the maximum number"));

  
while (!maximum) {
  maximum = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter a valid number!"));
}


let targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum + 1);
console.log(targetNum)

let guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your first guess!"));
let attempts = 1;

while(parseInt(guess) !== targetNum  || guess.toString !== "q") {
 if (guess > targetNum) {
   guess = prompt("too high! Enter a new guess")
 }
 else {
  guess = prompt("too low! Enter a new guess")
  attempts++;
}
}
console.log(`You got it! It took you ${attempts} guesses`)
```

Whenever I press q, it doesn't work. Can someone please explain to me why :) ?

Comment: `guess` is already a string. Converting it into a string is therefor a no-op. And `guess.toString` does not call the `.toString()` method, hence you compare a function with a string.

Comment: `parseInt("q")` will always be different to `targetNum` and therefor `guess.toString() !== "q"` won't ever be evaluated

Comment: _"The [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement. "_

Answer (score 0):

I put your variables on top to make it more clean. I also added an else if that breaks the loop when i type "q".

```
let maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the maximum number"));
let guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your first guess!"));
let attempts = 1;
let targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum + 1);


while (!maximum) {
   maximum = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter a valid number!"));
}
while(parseInt(guess) !== targetNum) {
   if (guess > targetNum) {
      guess = prompt("too high! Enter a new guess")
      attempts++;
   }
   else if(guess < targetNum){
      guess = prompt("too low! Enter a new guess")
      attempts++;
   }else if(guess == "q"){
      break;
   }
}
console.log(targetNum)
console.log(`You got it! It took you ${attempts} guesses`)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const guessNumberGame = {
  start_  : function(){
    let n = prompt( 'Enter the secret number:' );
    if( n ){
      if ( !isNaN( n ) ){
        this.guess_(n);
      }else{
        alert( 'That is not a valid number!' );
        this.start_();
      }
    }else{
      alert( 'Cancel the game!' );
    }
  },
  guess_ : function(n){
    const g = prompt( 'guess the number!' );
    if( g ){
      if ( !isNaN( g ) ){
        if( g > n ){
          alert( 'Too high!' );
          this.guess_(n);
        }
        else if( g < n ){
          alert( 'Too low!' );
          this.guess_(n);
        }
        else{
          alert( 'Correct!' );
          this.start_();
        }
      }else{
        alert( 'That is not a valid number!' );
        this.guess_(n);
      }
    }else{
      this.start_();
    }
  }
};

guessNumberGame.start_();
```

Comment: If you completely change the script of OP and make it unnecessarily more complicated (and why do all methods have an underscore at the end?) then at least explain your changes and why you made them.

Comment: Also this does not work as OP wants it to work. The input of `"q"` does not stop the game.